# How to remove a vendor from a symfony2 project?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

How to neatly remove vendor ?

SyliusCartBundle, that I'm installing, requires Stof 1.1.*, and my Symfony project has Stof 1.2.x. So I want to remove that Stof 1.2.

Is it comes down to removing:

- stof directory from vendor directory
- AppKernel line

And here the error output from shell:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[v1.1.0, 1.2.x-dev
].
    - Can only install one of: stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[v1.1.0, 1.2.x-dev
].
    - sylius/order-bundle v0.12.0 requires stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle 1.1.*
 -> satisfiable by stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[v1.1.0].
    - sylius/cart-bundle v0.12.0 requires sylius/order-bundle 0.12.*@dev -> sati
sfiable by sylius/order-bundle[v0.12.0].
    - Installation request for sylius/cart-bundle 0.12.* -> satisfiable by syliu
s/cart-bundle[v0.12.0].
    - Installation request for stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle == 1.2.9999999.99
99999-dev -> satisfiable by stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[1.2.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

- delete line from `AppKernel`
- remove any dependencies from the `config.yml`
- remove the require statement from the projects `composer.json`

If you still get an error than one of your other vendor packages is requiring the one you have deleted so you will either have to stay with the bundle or delete all depending bundles

Comment: No need to physically remove stof directory from vendor directory?

Comment: nope it will be automatically removed by the composer update command, the vendors you have of the compser.json will be checked against the installed ones and so that new will be installed existing will be updated if there is an update available and existing ones not listed in the json will be automatically removed